# element is null in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have a modal dialog box which is containing search field. when I select element from drop down list, I got an error "element is null". Can not understand why did I get this error. Following is my code.

```
<%= label_tag :Search_by %>
<select name="search" id="search" >
    <option value="0">Trainer</option>
    <option value="1">Venue</option>
    <option value="2">Country</option>
</select>

<div id="div_to_be_updated" style="float:right">
</div>

<%= observe_field 'search', :update => 'div_to_be_updated',:url => {:controller => 'events', :action=> 'pop_up_search' }, :with => "'is_delivery_address=' + escape(value)" %>
```

controller code::

```
def pop_up_search
  @trainers= Trainer.all
  @countries= Country.all

  if ["0"].include?(params[:is_delivery_address])
    render :partial => 'layouts/pop_up_trainer_search'
  else
    if ["1"].include?(params[:is_delivery_address])
      render :partial => 'calendar/pop_up_venu_search'
    else
      render :partial => 'layouts/pop_up_country_search'
    end
  end
end
```

_pop_up_trainer_search.html.erb

```
<span style="text-align: right">
    <% form_tag "/calendar/pop_up_trainer_view" do %>
        <%= collection_select("event", "trainer_id", @trainers , :id, :name, {:prompt => true}) %>
        <%= submit_tag "search" %>
    <% end%>
</span>
```

Why did I get this error? Can anybody help me to correct this?

Comment: Please post the entire exception backtrace

Comment: Look in your log to see exactly what url (and args) is being called by the JS observer.

Comment: I am only getting Error: element is null
Source File: http://localhost:3000/javascripts/prototype.js?1315993754
Line: 3588                                                          in my error console. And also my log file is also empty..What should I do?

Comment: @ mu is too short: It is my mistake.. Thank you... but how can I correct this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like your error is happening on the client, not at the server.

That means there's a problem with your JS.

That means that the `observe_field` is not being turned into good JS.

**Suggestions**

Examine the source of your web page, as it is sent from the server.

- Look at the Javascript that is observing the #search element.
- Check that there are no other elements with the search id
- Use Firebug or other JS debugger to follow the Javascript flow when a new value is selected in the select field

**Added** Since it works when in the main erb, but not the popup erb, a couple of ideas:

1. Don't re-use the `search` id in the popups. It should be a unique dom element. Different ways to handle this, one is to hide, not destroy the popup.
2. Confirm that the JS is being called when the popup dialog is created. -- Add an alert statement and see if it is evaluated.
3. Does it work the first time the dialog is created, but not on later times?
4. The JS debugger is your friend. Use it to carefully see what is happening on the browser. The Rails JS machinery is supposed to run JS that is in a partial but maybe there's a problem there.

Comment: @Rosh, now we're getting somewhere. See above.

Answer (score 0):

**Suggestions:**

- check your JS in Firebug console
- how does your form tag look like? do you have a :url set correctly?
- is your :with parameter correct?
- can you try to use symbols instead of strings when you reference DIVs? e.g. :search , :div_to_be_updated

  <%= observe_field :search, :update => :div_to_be_updated,:url => {:controller => 'events', 
           :action=> 'pop_up_search' }, :with => "'is_delivery_address=' + escape(value)" %>
- how do your params look like, when you get the call to your pop_up_search()
- does the DIV div_to_be_updated exist when you look in Firebug?

Comment: :with parameter is correct. I changed my div_to_be_updated and it exists. but nothing changed. It is still giving error.